# xpcom/jetpack observe all document loads

Tags: firefox-addon, document, observer-pattern, xpcom, firefox-addon-sdk

I write a Mozilla Jetpack based add-on that has to run whenever a document is loaded. For "toplevel documents" this mostly works using this code (`OserverService = require('observer-service')`):

```
    this.endDocumentLoadCallback = function (subject, data) {
        console.log('loaded: '+subject.location);
        try {
            server.onEndDocumentLoad(subject);
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.error(formatTraceback(e));
        }
    };
    ObserverService.add("EndDocumentLoad", this.endDocumentLoadCallback);
```

But the callback doesn't get called when the user opens a new tab using middle click or (more importantly!) for frames. And even this topic I only got through reading the source of another extension and not through the documentation.

So how do I register a callback that really gets called every time a document is loaded?

**Edit:** This seems to do what I want:

```
function callback (event) {
    // this is the content document of the loaded page.
    var doc = event.originalTarget;

    if (doc instanceof Ci.nsIDOMNSHTMLDocument) {
        // is this an inner frame?
        if (doc.defaultView.frameElement) {
            // Frame within a tab was loaded.
            console.log('!!! loaded frame:',doc.location.href);
        }
        else {
            console.log('!!! loaded top level document:',doc.location.href);
        }
    }
}

var wm = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);
var mainWindow = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
mainWindow.gBrowser.addEventListener("load", callback, true);
```

Got it partially from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads

Comment: Mozilla and XPCOM in general are very niche topics. You may be getting more useful answers faster by going to the IRC channel (those people are very friendly and helpful from my experiences)

Comment: @kizzx2 Do you have the address of that IRC channel?

Comment: #developers on irc.mozilla.org

Answer (score 0):

@kizzx2 you are better served with #jetpack

To the original question: why don't you use tab-browser module. Something like this:

```
var browser = require("tab-browser");

exports.main = function main(options, callbacks) {
initialize(function (config) {
    browser.whenContentLoaded(
        function(window) {
           // something to do with the window
           // e.g., if (window.locations.href === "something")
        }
    );
});
```

Much cleaner than what you do IMHO and (until we have official pageMods module) the supported way how to do this.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I guess I don't get page loads that aren't initiated by me this way. E.g. loads of frames and popups. I need to observe all loads.

Comment: Yes, this is just for new tabs.

Answer (score 0):

As of Addon SDK 1.0, the proper way to do this is to use the [page-mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) module.

(Under the hood it's implemented using the [document-element-inserted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Documents) observer service notification, you can use it in a regular extension or if page-mod doesn't suit you.)